# Javascript need to enable multiple textboxes after button click

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to enable multiple textboxes that have class name = `textfieldToClose`, but the following code won't work.

```js
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName('textfieldToClose');
$('#edit').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault()

  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    collection[i].style.border = '1px black solid' ? '' : '1px black solid';
    collection[i].enabled = true;
  }
  document.getElementById("save1").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById('edit').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row pl-4 pt-1 pb-1 border" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="altright">
    <input type="text" value="Value 1" disabled style="background-color: transparent;border: none" class="textfieldToClose" name="pkgname1"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="altright">
    <input type="text" value="123Rs" disabled style="background-color: transparent;border: none" class="textfieldToClose" name="pkgprice1"></input>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="edit">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the markup as well? It seems that you are not removing the `disabled` attribute

Comment: 1. You have jQuery, why not use it? 2. there is no attribute called enabled. You need to remove disabled or set `prop("disabled",false")` 3. Why not toggle a class? 4. You need to test  `collection[i].style.border == '1px black solid'` in your ternary, assuming the browser kept it in that case

Comment: Your ternary expression doesn't work as you expect `'1px black solid' ? '' : '1px black solid';` will always be true since `'1px black solid'` is not considered as *falsy*

Comment: @Cid thats an additional point

Comment: Also, don’t try to call preventDefault on a global `event` object, that will only work in certain browsers. Use the callback function parameter, as https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ shows.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please next time provide a [mcve] - we are missing save1 for example

Comment: `input` elements don't have an `enabled` property. Use `element.disabled = false` to "enable".

Answer (score 1):

1. You have jQuery, why not use it?
2. there is no attribute called enabled. You need to remove disabled or set prop("disabled",false")
3. Why not toggle a class? Or use CSS :disabled
4. You need to test collection[i].style.border == '1px black solid' in your ternary, assuming the browser kept it in that case
5. `</input>` is not necessary (or valid). Just close the tag with `/>`

Here is my suggestion

```js
var $collection = $('.textfieldToClose');
$('#edit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // not really necessary since it is type="button"
  $collection.each(function() { $(this).removeAttr("disabled") })
  $("#save1").show();
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```css
.textfieldToClose { border: 1px black solid; }
.textfieldToClose:disabled { background-color: transparent;border: none;}
#save1 { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row pl-4 pt-1 pb-1 border" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="altright">
    <input type="text" value="Value 1" disabled  class="textfieldToClose" name="pkgname1" />
  </div>
  <div class="altright">
    <input type="text" value="123Rs" disabled  class="textfieldToClose" name="pkgprice1" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" id="save1">Save</button>
</div>
```